# ErrorException - Undefined array key when using value from an Array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been trying to use the data from a Model result for a login page, but it's always throwing an Exception Error.

I can print the array itself, but when I try to call a specific key, and its prompting the Error above.

Here's the snippet of the code I'm working on.

**Route:**

`$routes->match(['get', 'post'], 'login-verif', 'UserCrud::loginVerify');`

**Controller**

```
public function loginVerify()
    {
        $session = session();
        $userModel = new UserModel();
        $username = $this->request->getVar('key1');
        $password = $this->request->getVar('key2');
        
        $data = $userModel->getLoginSession($username);
        //$data = $userModel->getLoginSession()->where('key1', $username)->first();
       if(isset($data)) {
            echo json_encode($data);  // This is me trying to print out the result from $data
            $pass = $data["key1"]; // This is the one throwing up errors
            $authenticatePassword = password_verify($password, $pass);
            if($authenticatePassword){
                $ses_data = [
                    'id' => $data['key_id'],
                    'username' => $data['key2'],
                    'name' => $data['key3'],
                    'isLoggedIn' => TRUE
                ];
                $session->set($ses_data);
                return redirect()->to('/users-list');
            
            }else{
                $session->setFlashdata('msg', 'Password is incorrect.');
                return redirect()->to('/login');
            }
        }else{
            $session->setFlashdata('msg', 'Email does not exist.');
            return redirect()->to('/login');
        }
    }
```

But whenever i try to run the code, its throwing the ErrorException error, even when i can echo the variables.

`Undefined array key "key1"`

Here's the result when i try to echo the array:

`[{"key0":"2","key1":"admin","key2":"User Admin","key3":"***","key4":"1","tracker_createdat":"2023-07-03 08:12:42"}]`

Appreciate any help!

Comment: You can not output an actual array with echo, that will only ever get you the _word_ "Array". You appear to have a text value containing JSON-encoded data here.

Comment: Can you do a `print_r($data)` and output the data? Also, paste the definition for `getLoginSession`

Comment: Looks like the `key1` and other `indexes` are part of a multidimensional array and exist on the first index of the `data` array. You can get them by `$data[0]['key1']`